# Python popen process does not stay running

Tags: python, linux, cron, tcpdump

I have a Python process that uses os.popen to run tcpdump in the background. It then reads and processes the output from tcpdump. The process runs in the background as a daemon. When I execute this process from the command line, it runs just fine--it fires up tcpdump and reads the output properly. However, I want this process to run automatically at boot and I've directed it to do so in cron. When I do this, my process is running (per the ps command) but tcpdump is not.

Is there some reason the behavior is different starting a process in cron vs starting it from the command line? My code looks something like this:

```
p = os.popen('/usr/sbin/tcpdump -l -i eth0')
while True:
   data = p.readline()
   # do something with data
```

Comment: Try opening it using `p = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/sbin/tcpdump'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE])`, and check `p.stderr` to see if tcpdump failed on startup for some reason. (which certainly appears to be the case). Maybe eth0 wasn't ready yet or something?

Comment: Thanks for getting me thinking about this and helping me fix it. Apparently, the interface wasn't up yet.

Answer (score 1):

`cron` will send you an email when there is a problem. So the first thing is to look into your mailbox (run `mailx` to access it).

If there is no mail, make sure the processes write messages to stdout/stderr when there is a problem.

Also: Check that you're using the correct user. On some systems, `tcpdump` needs to be run as `root`, so you need to install the job into `root`'s crontab (instead of the one of your normal user).